# How to change filename's encode type?

Tags: php, file, encode

I am going to change my filename's encode type from utf-8 to big5, and this is what I have so far:

```
$path = "stu_resume/104206002_87";
$result =iconv("utf-8", "big5", $path);
echo $result;
echo mb_detect_encoding($result);
```

Within the folder of 104206002_87, there are 2 files, which are **104206002_87_履歷, 104206002_87_自傳.** 
After the code above is executed, I found that there is nothing changed in the folder. Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do.. the commands you wrote change the encoding for the running php script, not the files...

Comment: @GuyL So if I'd like to change the filename's encode type, what should I do? Sorry for the blur explanation. :(

Comment: Well you should open them read and re-encode the contents, and rewrite them. I'de also (at least) rephrase the question...

Comment: have you tried mb_convert_encoding()

Comment: @sandeepsoni Yes, I have tried that one by: `$paths = "stu_resume/104206002_87/104206002_87_自傳.pdf";
 $d = dir($paths);
 $d_new = iconv("big5", "utf-8", $paths);
 $encode = mb_detect_encoding($d_new, array('big5', 'utf-8'));
 var_dump($encode);` It did output the encode type to be big-5, but it seems that the filename still hasn't change.

Answer (score 0):

`iconv()` doesn't modify files. It just converts a string. In this case, the string it's converting is `""stu_resume/104206002_87"` -- since this string only contains ASCII characters, nothing changes when it's converted from UTF-8 to Big5.

If you want to rename the files in the directory with that name, you will need to do so explicitly, e.g.

```
$iter = new DirectoryIterator("stu_resume/104206002_87");
foreach ($iter as $file) {
    if (!$file->isDot()) {
        $old_name = $file->getPathname();
        $new_name = iconv("utf-8", "big5", $old_name);
        rename($old_name, $new_name);
    }
}
```